# NoSuchMethodError HttpServletRequest.getServletContext() on Servlet >3.0

Tags: java, servlets, gradle, jetty, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to set up a WebSocketServlet in Jetty.

I've set up a servlet according to [this guide](https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html#d0e22394), and implemented the WebSocket according to [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-api-annotations.html). However, when I run `gradle jettyRun` and attempt to open a connection (using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo)) to `ws://localhost:8080/myProjectName/echo`), I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletContext()` ([full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/tjCyB3vJ))

I [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext()) that this method was only introduced in servlet 3.0 - however, since I'm using `servlet-api:3.1.0`, I believe I should have that method?

I'm reasonably sure that the routing in my `WEB-INF/web.xml` is correct, since when I try to hit another url (`ws://localhost:8080/myProjectName/echo123`, for instance), I don't get error output on the terminal.

---

Files:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin : 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.2.v20150730'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:9.0.0.M3'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:9.1.3.v20140225'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EchoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.scubbo.myprojectname.EchoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EchoServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/echo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

src/main/java/org/scubbo/myprojectname/EchoServlet.java

```
package org.scubbo.myprojectname;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;
import org.scubbo.myprojectname.sockets.EchoSocket;

public class EchoServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(10000);
        factory.register(EchoSocket.class);
    }
```

src/main/java/org/scubbo/myprojectname/sockets/EchoSocket.java

```
package org.scubbo.myprojectname.sockets;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;

@WebSocket
public class EchoSocket {

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onText(Session session, String message) {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            System.out.printf("Echoing back message [%s]%n", message);
            session.getRemote().sendString(message, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're compiling against 3.1, which is how it *compiles* - but what version of the servlet API does your very of Jetty *implement*?

Comment: You might want to read http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html and then check which version of Jetty you're using. (You appear to be compiling against 9.3.2, but I suggest you check the logs to be sure.)

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-javaee.html suggests that Jetty 9.1.x should include Servlet Specification API 3.1. I'll remove the other two Jetty dependencies, depend only on jetty-all:9.1.3, and try again.

Comment: I'm concerned that the docs page I referred to before doesn't even mention 9.1 - you might want to skip to 9.2 or 9.3...

Comment: OK! Updated to jetty-all:9.3.2.v20150730, and I'm getting a new error - "javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, WebSocket support unavailable".

According to the third paragraph here (https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html#d0e22394), WebSockets are only available from inside the Jetty Container - but the spec for JettyRun (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html) suggests that it would do just that ("Deploys an exploded web application to an embedded Jetty web container"). I'll keep digging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem you are having is that you had 2 conflicting versions of the servlet api in your classpath (not that uncommon, as there's a half-dozen odd maven coordinates for that artifact, which makes conflict resolution difficult for maven or gradle)

Don't use jetty-all with your project, that artifact isn't meant to be used from a project.  See [past responses about this](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).

The problem you are having with WebSocket support should be filed as a separate question on stackoverflow.

Ask a specific question about your websocket issue, and I'll answer there.