# Using Websockets in Jetty

Tags: gradle, websocket, jetty

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296856/nosuchmethoderror-httpservletrequest-getservletcontext-on-servlet-3-0/32302306#32302306) for previous question.

I'm trying to set up an application using Websockets and running in Jetty. When I run [gradle jettyRun](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html), however, I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, WebSocket support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.init(WebSocketServerFactory.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

[This page](https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html) suggests that Websockets are only available "within the Jetty container", but I would have thought that the Jetty plugin would do so by default. Do I need to reconfigure it somehow?

EDIT: [This issue](https://issues.gradle.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GRADLE-1956) suggests that the Jetty plugin targets an old (and incompatible-with-websockets) version of Jetty. It's pretty old, though - I don't know if the claim that it's unresolved is still true. I'll try running Jetty directly, rather than through the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a correct assumption.

The class `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder` tells you that you are running Jetty 6.x marked EOL (End of Life) back in 2010.

The project moved to the Eclipse Foundation in 2008, with the first release of the new "Eclipse Jetty" (on the `org.eclipse.jetty` namespace) version 7.0.0 in October 2009.

The WebSocket support you are attempting to use will require Jetty 9.2+

You might want to look into NOT using the gradle plugin but just using an embedded jetty instance from a project specific runner module of your own design.

eg:

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.cookbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class WebAppContextFromFileSystem
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        Path warPath = new File("webapps/hello.war").toPath().toRealPath();
        System.err.println("WAR File is " + warPath);

        // A very bare bones example (see other examples for
        // how to use WebAppContext Configurations to enable
        // jndi, annotations, etc ...)
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar(warPath.toUri().toASCIIString());

        server.setHandler(webapp);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

See the embedded jetty examples for more details.

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/master/examples/embedded

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I haven't abandoned this question - I'll accept it as the answer once I can get it working, but I still haven't been able to successfully run Jetty embedded, despite your examples. In particular, even the super-simplistic example here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-minimal-servlet or here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html#d0e19135 give a 500 response every time. I'll keep trying!

Comment: Nothing apparently wrong showing up in logging:

$ java -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog -jar build/libs/myProject-all-1.0.jar
2015-09-08 00:17:48.546:INFO::main: Logging initialized [at]298ms
2015-09-08 00:17:48.605:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-09-08 00:17:48.665:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector[at]deb6432{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-09-08 00:17:48.666:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started [at]422ms

[no further logging, even after requests are made]

Comment: Hmm - when I dropped the dependency on jetty-all, and switched to explicit dependencies, the example works! Weird.

My original build.gradle had:
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:9.3.2.v20150730'
And working version has
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.2.v20150730'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:9.3.3.v20150827'
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.3.3.v20150827'

Accepting - thanks!

Comment: [Don't use jetty-all as a dependency in your project](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html), its not designed for that.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to lookup which (Maven/Gradle/etc.) package contains/is-the-authority-for which (Java) package? For instance, I was originally depending on "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:9.0.0.M3", expecting it to provide "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session", but it doesn't appear to to so.

Comment: Don't use version `9.0.0.M3`, that's a super early milestone (even pre-beta), use one of the released and stable releases of Jetty 9.3.x or 9.2.x